# При установке serial выдает ошибку "AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'serial'

Tags: python

В питоне особо не разбираюсь, но тут пришлось использовать. Установил библиотеку serial через pip3, всё прошло гладко, 'import serial' ошибки не выдаёт, но вот в таком коде:

```
import serial  
r = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)  
f = open('C:\statistic\stat.txt', 'w')
e = 0
while(e == 0):
t = int(r.readline())
print(t)
f.write(str(t))
f.close()
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> File "", line 1, in 
>      ser = serial.Serial('COM3')
>   AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: вы случайно свой файл не назвали `serial.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите `pyserial`, а не `serial`.

```
>> pip install pyserial
```

UPDATE !!!

Может быть еще такое решение, как в следующем вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Смысл, что вы должны делать импорт модулю, вот так: `from serial import serial`

Кстати, обратите внимание еще и на этот ответ: `Problem occurs when you import 'something' when your python file name is 'something.py'`.
Имеетеся в виду, что название вашего файло должно отличатся от импортируемых в этом файле модулей.

Comment: > И исправление состоит в том, чтобы удалить оба, а затем переустановить pyserial